# $\Sigma _{n>1} \dfrac{n^{\ln{n}}}{(\ln{n})^n}$ is convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Supposing the sequence $u_n = \dfrac{n^{\ln{n}}}{(\ln{n})^n}$, is the the serie $\displaystyle \Sigma_{n>1}{u_n}$ convergent or divregent?

I've tried to use Alembert theorem, but in vain.

Comment: If you write $u_n$ as $e^{\text{something}}$, do you see whether it converges then?

Comment: That's what I've did using Alembert theorem

Comment: So what exponent did you get?

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, $u_1=?$

Comment: I went ahead and removed the $u_1$ term because (in my mind) it is clearly an error. Feel free to edit it back if it was supposed to be there (but be sure to include an explanation).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using the Root Test, also known as the Cauchy Test. The $n$-th root of the bottom is $\ln n$. The $n$-th root of the top is $e^{(\ln n)^2/n}$. From this you should be able to conclude that the $n$-th root of the whole thing approaches $0$ as $n\to\infty$.